# Change MySQL Collation for large database

Tags: mysql

I have a database with size 4.4 GB and more than 220K rows.

I am using **utf8_general_ci** Collation

Now I want to change to **utf8mb4_general_ci**

I just open the phpMyAdmin and select all columns I want to change

It took 2 hours to finish the query and in the end, I got the same Collation **utf8_general_ci**

Might there is an error and it failed to change the Collation

So what the solution for a large database

I just take a backup file in the cPanel

Comment: The database is MySQL, not mysqli or phpMyAdmin.

Comment: yes sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can change the collation of your db, either each table individually or all tables, on the Operations tab under Collation section.

---

If you'd rather want to write query, you can try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```